# Can't load dynamic library php_openssl.dll

Tags: php, dll, installation, phpstorm, php-openssl

I figured out why this is not working, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image: Error message]

At the bottom there is a PHP Warning saying it cannot load the dynamic library because it cannot find it. It is looking in the C: drive when it should be looking in D:\Other\php-7.0.13-Win32-VC14-x64\ext\php_openssl.dll

How do I change it so it looks in the right spot? Do I edit the php.ini file? Which part? I've tried looking myself and have come up empty.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to edit php.ini into your php folder, where are specified php extensions (Lines like : extension=XXX.dll).

Just add comment before, or try to get the extension.

Best regards